# Running jenkins jobs on any available slave

Tags: jenkins, groovy, cicd

Can someone please let me know how do I run a job on any available Jenkins cloud slave? I have tried assigning the same label to all 4 slaves but only the first slave is spinning up. I do not want to explicitly specify each slave label in the declarative pipeline. I have looked a lot but cannot find a resolution. I don't want to execute jobs on the master node. Any help would be appreciated, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try [this plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/leastload/) - by default jobs will be allocated to the node they last run on even if others are available.

Comment: Thanks Pamela, I tried this but it is still spinning up on the the first slave? any other ideas?

Comment: @Mo do you mean you want to run the job on all avialable cloud slaves in parallel?

Comment: @Noam Nope, I just want any job to be built on any available slave without explicitly stating each jenkins slave label in the pipeline.

Comment: @Mo99709 you mean `agent any` in declarative pipeline?

Comment: @Noam That doesn't work I have tried that sadly. It just stays in the status "Waiting for the next available executor". I don't want builds happening on the master node.

Comment: @Mo99709 you need to make sure that all your nodes or cloud nodes are configured to **Use this node as much as possible** under the **Usage** configuration option and not to **Only build jobs with label expressions matching this node**.

Comment: @Noam I don't see an option for usage for the cloud slaves, I can only see it for the master slave under "Configure System"

Comment: @Mo99709 which cloud slave are you using?

Comment: @Noam I am using aws ecs.